# Constructing a special sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, number-theory

I'm trying to solve the second part of the following exercise which is question 32 in Section 1.5 of *Real Analysis* by Folland.

Suppose $\{\alpha_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty} \subset (0, 1)$. Then:

1. $\prod_{j=1}^{\infty} (1 - \alpha_j)>0$.
   if and only if $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \alpha_j < \infty$.
2. Given $\beta \in (0, 1)$, exhibit a sequence $\{\alpha_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\prod_{j=1}^{\infty} (1 - \alpha_j)= \beta$.

How can I prove the second part of the statement?
I am pretty sure that it should be solved by induction. But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If $\beta_n$ is an arbitrary strictly monotonous sequence  $$\beta_n \downarrow \beta$$
We define
$$1-\alpha_1=\beta_1$$

$$\implies \alpha_1=1-\beta_1 \in (0,1)$$
and
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(1-\alpha_i)=\beta_n$$
This gives
$$\beta_{n+1}=\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(1-\alpha_i)=(1-\alpha_{n+1})\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-\alpha_i)=(1-\alpha_{n+1})\beta_n$$
$$\implies \alpha_{n+1}=1-\frac{\beta_{n+1}}{\beta_n}$$

Because of $0<\beta_{n+1}<{\beta_n}$ we have $\frac{\beta_{n+1}}{\beta_n} \in (0,1)$ and $1-\frac{\beta_{n+1}}{\beta_n} \in (0,1)$